# How to upload an image to MySql DB using ajax......?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form with three input's including image file. When i submit my form with 
"form action="upload.php" it works fine. But when i try to do it in ajax it shows me "THERE IS NO RESPONSE". Could anyone tell me how to do it.....?

ajax Code:

```
//
$('#uploadForm').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: url+'images/ajaxupload.php',
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        method: 'post',
        data: $('#uploadForm').serialize(),
        success: function(){
           alert('Image Uploaded');
        }

    });
}); 
//
```

Comment: Use jquery plugin like this: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in form tag... because if you do not use this.. your file input value will not be submitted to next page...

Comment: Yes......... I found that it is a "CROSS DOMAIN (CORS)" problem....could u tell me how to resolve it.....?

Comment: There is a method in ajax "crossDomain: true"... use this and than let me know if this helps or not?

Comment: i've tried to submit my form by ajax on "on change" by calling a function "upload_image(){ ajax for submitting form }"....this also gives me cross domain error....